# Best scheduling jobs

Tags: algorithm

I have been working on this question and can't seem to find the right answer. Can someone please help me with this?

We are given `N` jobs `[1,..,N]`. We'll get a salary `S(i) >= 0` for getting a job `i` done, and a deduction `D(i) >= 0` that adds up for each day passing.

We'll need `T(i)` days to complete job `i`. Suppose the job `i` is done on day `d`, we'll get `S(i) - d.D(i)` in reward. The reward can be negative if `d` is too big.
We can switch jobs in the process and work on jobs in any order, meaning if we start job 1 that takes 5 days on day 1, we don't have to spend 5 consecutive days working on job 1.

How can we decide the best schedule of the jobs, so that we can complete all the jobs and get maximum salary?

Comment: It looks like a knapsack problem: _https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem_

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `S(i)` is fixed - whenever the job is finished, and the only thing that can change is the deduction for the when it is finished. Following these assumptions, order the jobs so the ones that will cost the most to delay are performed first, and the cheaper ones last - thus reducing the overall deductions.

Comment: I think this approach is actually too simplistic.  Is this a homework problem where N is unbounded or a real world scheduling problem where N has bounds?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov Thanks for your suggestion. I think that's one of the things we need to consider. How can we consider that and also S(i) (which is fixed and different for each job) to get the max reward?

Comment: @Bill N is unbounded for this problem

Comment: @shapiroyaacov that was my first idea as well, but on second thought, the days to complete also play an important role. It is better to complete many short jobs with slightly lower deduction first instead of one very long job with higher deduction.

Comment: @CsIsFun - I don't think you need to consider `S(i)` since you need to get all the jobs done and `S(i)` doesn't ever change. Basically, the total sum is a fixed number...

Comment: @Henry - that is what I meant. "order the jobs so the ones that will cost the most to delay are performed first" means to take into account the cost of delay **and** how long it will take. Some sort of weighted cost

Comment: @shapiroyaacov ok, but the weighted cost depends on the other jobs that are in the mix, i.e. the ones that are not yet completed. So the order of the jobs has influence on the weighted cost.

Comment: @Henry - I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `D(i)` and `T(i)` are enough to decide the order. Basically, take the *one day delay* cost defined as `ODD(i) = D(i)/T(i)` and order by that. Again, not sure this is the best solution, but it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov We can't calculate ODD(i) = D(i) / T(i) since D(i) is itself the delay cost per day. So how do we get the weighted cost?

Comment: @CsIsFun - So use `X(i) = T(i) * D(i)` to see who will give the most expensive delay to the system and order that by ascending order...

Answer (score 3):

I think shapiro is right.  You need to determine an appropriate weighted cost formula for each task.  It has to take into account the days remaining, the per day deduction, and maybe total deduction.

Once you have the weighted cost you can sort the task list by the weighted cost and perform one day of work on the first task in the list (should be the one that will cost the most if not completed).  Then recalculate the weighted cost for all the tasks now that a day has passed, sort the list, and repeat until all tasks are complete.

Generally when you are optimizing schedules in the real world this is the approach.  Figure out which task should be worked on first, do some work on it, then recalculate to see if you should switch tasks or keep working on the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Following the above discussion:

For each job `i`, calculate the *one day delay* cost as `X(i) = D(i) / T(i)` and order the jobs by it. Maybe even just order by `D(i)` since when you choose one job you are **not** choosing the others - so it makes sense to choose the one with the most expensive deduction. Perform the jobs by this order to minimize the deduction fees.

Again, this is assuming that `S(i)` is a fixed reward for each job, independent on the exact day it is finished by, and that all jobs need to be performed.

Comment: counter example: D1=5, T1=5, D2=4, T2=1, D3=4, T3=1; doing 2 and 3 first is better than doing 1 first.

Comment: @Henry - This example shows that my initial suggestion of ordering  by `X(i)=D(i)/T(i)` can work...

Comment: I think you can justify D(i)/T(i) by considering two adjacent jobs and working out what happens to the total cost if you swap them. If they are not ordered according to D(i)/T(i) then the swap will improve matters.

Answer (score 0):

First forget about S(i). You are doing all the jobs you get all the rewards anyway.

Second there's no point to interrupt a task and switch to another.Let's say you have jobs A and B. The deduction you get for the one that finishes last is the same (it's going to take T(A) + T(B) to finish it regardless of how you schedule). The deduction for the other job can only increase if you switch because it's going to take longer to finish it. So you're best if you drop the switch.

Now the problem is to order the tasks so that you get minimum amount of penalty. I'm not sure what's next.
You can pick the first job to minimize T(x) * sum(d) (since you commit to dong job x everything will incur T(x) days delay).
Or you can pick the last job since you know you're going to pay sum(T) * d(x) (you know when it's going to finish).
One says order by T(x) the other says order by d(x) and they are both wrong.

Likely the solution is some dynamic programming in this space, but it escapes me at the moment.